# Android intent startActivityForResult doesn't return properly

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, oauth-2.0

I have mainactivity and intentActivity.

- mainActivity - Normal main activity
- intentActivity - For Twitter OAth request Browser will be launched by this activity

How do I know whether or not the intent activity is correct? In mainActivity I used following codes

In Onclick of a button I used:

```
startActivityForResult(i,request_code);
```

also I added following function

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
{
  if(requestCode==1) 
   {
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
      {
          Toast.makeToast(getBaseContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
      {
     else
      {
          Toast.makeToast(getBaseContext(),"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
      }
  }
}
```

But for my surprise I'm getting **"Failed"** before browser opens.. But I wish **Success** to be displayed after returning from browser.

Comment: are you calling setResult on your second activity?

Comment: no i guess.. just i looked over Contacts example.. As they pass intent to content.Intent.ACTION_PICK they are getting result code by default. Is this default action only for system intents?

Answer (score 1):

You need make sure that before you call finish in your IntentActivity that your call [setResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29) and set it to success.

Comment: Thanks Kurtis. I have doubt i followed a Contacts example.. As they pass intent to content.Intent.ACTION_PICK they are getting result code by default. Is this default action only for system intents?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Actual Scenario is i have a update button which calls this Twitter Intent activity which in turns opens browser and initializes OAth tokens and it automatically redirects to my MainActivity. But here i wish when it redirects i need to be notified.

Comment: as you said i added setResult just before **context.startActivity(new Intent(context,mainActivity.class));** but when i get back result in onActivityResult() method its value is 0 (means RESULT_CANCELLED). i didnt cancel any intent its redirected only right?